# I want to access a specific indexed object from object of array of REDUX STORE in REDUX REDUCER

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to access a specific indexed object from object of array of REDUX STORE in REDUX REDUCER. But what would be the best and simplest way to do it.

> This is the object (array of object)

```
const formData = [
{
    name : 'Aman jat',
    gender : 'male'
},
{
    name : 'Ravina',
    gender : 'female'
}
```

]

> > This is what i want to do ::

```
const reducer = (state=formData,action) => {
  if(action.type=='INSERT_INFO') {
      return {
          ...state,
        state[0].name : action.payload_name1 <<<< this is my problem
      }
  }
  else 
    return state
}
```

Comment: Could we see your action where you get this info?

Comment: And what is the issue if you use a object with `firstName:' '` instead of using first index of state? what is your goal with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly as "you want to update the name property of the first object in the state array", you probably want to do

```js
      return [
        { ...state[0], name: action.payload_name1 },
        ...state.slice(1)
      ]
```

Seeing that you are just learning I have the usual PSA though: This is a pretty old style of redux that we are not really encouraging to teach any more. If you are following a tutorial teaching you this, that tutorial is probably very outdated. Please follow the official redux tutorials over at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index for up-to-date information.
In modern redux with the officially recommended redux toolkit (and only there, not with the style you are using!), this could actually be written as

```
state[0].name = action.payload_name1
```